# How to package electron app as a window service

Tags: windows, powershell, electron, electron-builder

I have successfully packaged my electron app appx. I want to run this app as a service. So it will always run and auto start on boot.

Is it possible to do this? If yes, how?

Can run a powershell script in the install process?